# How to centered the image in slide show?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use Nivo Slider plugin. I have an image (width = 2000px). I want to centered the image in the center of the slide.

My Desktop width is 1280. If I open the side I need the crop 360px from start and end of the image and show 1280px from the center.

If I resize the browser i just need to see the center.

Is it possible to implement this. I do not want the slide to be reponsive.

Comment: Don't aim to center to _your browser dimensions_ in particular. Aim to center it for _any_ browser dimension.

Comment: Things like `text-align: center` are agnostic to how wide a user's screen is.

Comment: No this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of Nivo slider, but the best way to center an image is the following

Here would be a sample of html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <img some image here/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS will be set up like this:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
.slider {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
img {
    width:2000px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-1000px;
}
```

This centers the image on any screen.  The img CSS places the left side of the image 50% across the screen (or centered).  Then you have to give the left margin a negative number half of the width of the image to place the center point of the image on the center point of the screen.